# How to insert another JSON, in the POST cURL request JSON data?

Tags: bash, curl, escaping

my `report` json looks like this:

```
{
  "passed": 11,
  "total": 11,
  "collected": 11
}
```

I defined a variables `test_report` and assigned the above value to it. But unable to use it in curl command? I'm seeing error as `invalid_payload` gcloud build logs

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud:latest
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  dir: 'workspace'
  env:
  - 'TEST_REPORT=${_TEST_REPORT}'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    cd /workspace
#Installing jq
    apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y curl unzip groff jq bc less
#testing jq is successfully installed or not
    jq --help
    cat mezi_automation_test_report.json
#assgined summary object to test_report file
    jq .summary mezi_automation_test_report.json > test_report
#check test_report file is displayed with summary object or not
    cat test_report
    report=$(cat test_report)
#check report variable has summary object or not
    echo report

    curl --location --request POST '$_SLACK_WEBHOOK' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-raw '{
        "channel":"$_CHANNEL",
        "username":"Cloudbuild",
        "icon_url":"$_ICON_URL",
        "text":"Test Report",
        "blocks": [
            {
                "type": "section",
                "text": {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": " Test Report *`$_BRANCH`* branch on QA"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "divider"
            },
            {
                "type": "section",
                "text": {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                  "text": "Version: *$_VERSION*\n TEST_REPORT: *"${report}"*"
                }
            }
        ]
    }'
```

Comment: effectively the question should be, how to insert JSON or run time variables in the curl data! It's nothing to do with google cloud build or build-triggers

Comment: Yes, you are right, thought it was about google cloud build as I am using it for build, deploy and testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

anything inside the `'` single quote can not be interpreted or read as a regex, so you gotta close it first and then use any bash command/variable. After that you can start the single quote again to append the remaining part of the string/json.

NOTE: if the bash command has a special output like a json value, enclose it in a double quote `"`

```
test_report=$(jq .summary mezi_automation_test_report.json)
curl "http://localhost/send" -d '{"text":'"$test_report"' } '
```

or if you want more control, parse each data value separately

```
passed=$(jq .summary.passed mezi_automation_test_report.json)
total=$(jq .summary.total mezi_automation_test_report.json)
collected=$(jq .summary.collected mezi_automation_test_report.json)
curl "http://localhost/send" -d '{"text":"Test Report: \nPassed: '$passed' \nTotal: '$total' \nCollected: '$collected' \nEnd of Report" } '
```

Comment: Worked! Defined variable for total, collected and passed and added them in curl data as below:

`"text": "Version: *$_VERSION*\n TEST_REPORT: *Total Tests ran:'$total_tests'*\n *Collected Tests:'$collected_tests'*\n *Passed Tests: '$passed_tests'* \n *Failed Tests: ''*"`

Thank you so much @s4p3r_c1n0s, saved my time, thanks a ton.